# Call fragment method from Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

My problem it's that I created a default Bottom Navigation Activity and I want to call a fragment method from MainActivity. The problem is that I 'm not able to take a reference of the fragment.
I tried all type of solution here in stackOverFlow.

a lot of method is deprecated.

//MAIN ACTIVITY

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        HomeFragment fragment = (HomeFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_home);
        fragment.sayHi();
    }
```

//FRAGMENT

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
    public void sayHi(){
        Log.d("hi", "hi");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)? What have you tried?

Comment: There are many design patterns to help you achieve this. You can create an interface in your fragment and invoke the method of the interface in your fragment and implement the interface in your activity. Bear in mind this way you will do what you want in your activity and not in fragment. Normally you can get your fragment instance in your activity but for that I would expect you to show what you tried